# bash | How to get value of %MEM from TOP command

Tags: bash, top-command

[image]

How can I grep easily the value of %MEM only from TOP of specific user (e.g tomcat) on console:

```
top -u tomcat | grep ????
```

expected output:

```
0.1
```

Comment: Use `awk`, not `grep`. Then you can easily specify the field number.

Comment: @Barmar: Ok, that was too easy :) The next problem is now: 1. I get several values of tomcat user and 2. have to end the TOP command explicitly with q or ALT+C. How can I ensure that only the highest value is displayed and that the top command is automatically ended?

Comment: 2. Use `top -b -n 1` to run one iteration in batch mode, instead of repeating in interactive mode.

Comment: 1. Use the sorting option `-o`, and exit the awk script after printing the first matching line.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I grep easily the value of %MEM only from TOP of specific user (e.g tomcat) on console?

This just shows the %MEM values:

```
top -b -n 1 -u tomcat -o %MEM | awk \
    'BEGIN {p=0} /%MEM/ {p=1; getline} {if (p) print $10}'
```

This runs `top` with -b (batch / background / script mode), only once (-n 1), for user tomcat, order by memory. Pass that information to `awk` to discard all before %MEM (handled by the p=0 -> 1 change).

This produces a list like:

```
0.2
0.1
0.1
0.0
```

If you just wish the top value, add this after the `awk`:

```
| head -1
```

If you wish to total it, change `awk` to:

```
'BEGIN {p=0} /%MEM/ {p=1; getline} {if (p) t+=$10} END {print t}'
```